# How to check if a lazy val is initialized without initializing it?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to determine if a lazy val is initialized, without initializing it?

```
object TheApp {
    lazy val optionalSubsystem = {
        // ...
        subsystem
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        bootSubsystemA(this)
        bootSubsystemB(this)

        if (/* optionalSubsystem is initialized */) {
            // more dependencies
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, but what determines if optionalSubsystem is going to be brought up?  is it runtime information? or compile-time information?

Comment: All runtime. I found a way: `optionalSubsystem` has a side-effect–it boots an actor. I check for the side-effect, until this is answered better.

Comment: "I boot an Akka actor. If the actor is booted, I want to supervise it". This use case should be stated in the question, if that is what you really want to know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question, and I hate when people do this, but I'm going to do it anyway. I think the best response is: A lazy val isn't appropriate for this, so define a type that does support what you need.

You'll have to refer to the variable as `optionalSubsystem()` rather than `optionalSubsystem`, but that's *A Good Thing*, because with the design you want, obtaining that reference is an observably side-effecting procedure.

```
class Lazy[A](f: => A, private var option: Option[A] = None) {

  def apply(): A = option match {
    case Some(a) => a
    case None => val a = f; option = Some(a); a
  }

  def toOption: Option[A] = option

}

scala> val optionalSubsystem = new Lazy { "a" }
optionalSubsystem: Lazy[java.lang.String] = Lazy@1210267

scala> optionalSubsystem.toOption.isDefined
res1: Boolean = false

scala> optionalSubsystem()
res2: java.lang.String = a

scala> optionalSubsystem.toOption.isDefined
res12: Boolean = true
```

**Edit** - Here's another revision with some modifications thanks to Tomas Mikula:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Lazy {

  def lazily[A](f: => A): Lazy[A] = new Lazy(f)

  implicit def evalLazy[A](l: Lazy[A]): A = l()

}

class Lazy[A] private(f: => A) {

  private var option: Option[A] = None

  def apply(): A = option match {
    case Some(a) => a
    case None => val a = f; option = Some(a); a
  }

  def isEvaluated: Boolean = option.isDefined

}
```

This lets you write `lazily { ... }` instead of `new Lazy { ... }`, and `optionalSubsystem` instead of `optionalSubsystem()`.

```
scala> import Lazy._
import Lazy._

scala> val optionalSubsystem = lazily { "a" }
optionalSubsystem: Lazy[String] = Lazy@3d0d54

scala> optionalSubsystem.isEvaluated
res0: Boolean = false

scala> optionalSubsystem: String
res1: String = a

scala> optionalSubsystem.isEvaluated
res2: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Better design is *good*. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This isn't thread-safe. One can say either, "It's easy to make it so", or, "There are better ways to coordinate multiple threads/actors."

Comment: @som-snytt I have no thread-safety requirements. The thread that's booting the system is simply going to die in a few moments, so it's not an issue.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil I see, so if optionalSub is set by bootSubA, it's done on the main thread. thx.

Comment: I like this solution. I created a [modification](https://gist.github.com/TomasMikula/7651866) where you can use `lazily { ... }` instead of `new Lazy { ... }` and replaced `toOption` with `isEvaluated: Boolean`.

Comment: The `implicit evalLazy` is a nice touch, too. I'm appending your modifications to my answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
object TheApp {

    private var _optionalSubsystemInitialized = false

    def optionalSubsystemInitialized = _optionalSubsystemInitialized

    lazy val optionalSubsystem = {
        _optionalSubsystemInitialized = true
        subsystem
    }

}
```

Whether is it really appropriate to have such side effects in the initialization code of a `lazy val` is another question.

Comment: I'd say it is, strictly, inappropriate. I agree with the bit quoted by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959777/why-would-i-want-to-re-implement-lazy : "Avoid using lazyness when lazyness is required by semantics. In these cases it's better to be explicit since it makes the cost model explicit, and side effects can be controlled more precisely."

Comment: @ChrisMartin - If you agree with that quote, does that mean you can explain what it means? The question you linked to is my question, and no one ever posted a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @DaoWen - I've been thinking about your question, and I can't come up with any convincing answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about this workaround?

```
val used = new AtomicBoolean(false)

lazy val o: String = {
  used.set(true)
  "aaa"
}

if (used.get()) { /* initialized */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

But of course you can.  A field is just a field.

```
package lazyside

object Lazy

class Foo {
  lazy val foo = 7
  lazy val bar = { Lazy ; 8 }
}

object Test extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{ currentMirror => cm }
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  val x = new Foo

  // method 1: reflect the underlying field
  val im = cm reflect x
  val f  = (typeOf[Foo] declaration TermName("foo")).asTerm.accessed.asTerm
  def foo_? = x synchronized ((im reflectField f).get != 0)

  def yn(b: Boolean) = if (b) "yes" else "no"
  Console println s"Is foo set yet? ${yn(foo_?)}"

  // method 2: check a benign side effect like a class load
  val m = classOf[ClassLoader].getDeclaredMethod("findLoadedClass", classOf[String])
  m setAccessible true
  def bar_? = (m invoke (x.getClass.getClassLoader, "lazyside.Lazy$")) != null
  Console println s"Is bar set yet? ${yn(bar_?)}"

  Console println s"I see that foo is ${x.foo}."
  Console println s"Is foo set yet? ${yn(foo_?)}"
  Console println s"I see that bar is ${x.bar}."
  Console println s"Is bar set yet? ${yn(bar_?)}"
  Console println s"I see that x is loaded by a ${x.getClass.getClassLoader.getClass}"
}
```

The caveat is that thread-safety of `foo_?` relies on the lazy computation acquiring the monitor of the instance `x`.  There is talk of changing that.

Also, obviously, testing the field value only works if the init value is not the default value (`null.asInstanceOf[T]`).

The second method relies on the class `Lazy$` getting loaded by the lazy init. It would be a bit safer to squirrel the object inside Foo.  In any case, that particular side-effect is one-shot. That might satisfy the use case of subsystem start-up.

With the unsurprising output:

> ```
> Is foo set yet? no
> Is bar set yet? no
> I see that foo is 7.
> Is foo set yet? yes
> I see that bar is 8.
> Is bar set yet? yes
> I see that x is loaded by a class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader
> ```

Compiled in 2.11.  For 2.10, use `newTermName` instead of `TermName`.

Comment: IMO the biggest problem is that you're testing for a default value which may well be the true value of the initialized field, and your example of a side effect check is too complicated. Why not, then, just set a flag in the lazy initializer?

Comment: I noted the problem of distinguishing the default value, which doesn't actually apply to the use case; my idea for the useful side effect is that if you're loading a subsystem, probably you're loading a new class, so that's a handy test.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stay immutable, you have to handle the state change.

You can use the following Lazy in order to do what you want:

```
trait Lazy[T] {
  def act[U](f: T => U): (Lazy[T], U)
  def actIfInitialized[U](f: T => U): (Lazy[T], Option[U])
  def isInitialized: Boolean
}

case class UnInitializedLazy[T](builder: () => T) extends Lazy[T] {
  override def isInitialized: Boolean = false

  override def act[U](f: T => U): (Lazy[T], U) = {
    InitializedLazy(builder()).act(f)
  }

  override def actIfInitialized[U](f: T => U): (Lazy[T], Option[U]) = {
    (this, None)
  }
}

case class InitializedLazy[T](thing: T) extends Lazy[T] {
  override def isInitialized: Boolean = false

  override def act[U](f: T => U): (Lazy[T], U) = {
    (this, f(thing))
  }

  override def actIfInitialized[U](f: T => U): (Lazy[T], Option[U]) = {
    (this, Some(f(thing)))
  }
}
```

you would use it this way:

```
class example extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  it should "initialize and act" in {
    val lazyBob: Lazy[String] = UnInitializedLazy(() => "Bob")
    val (bob, upperBob) = personToUpper(lazyBob)

    upperBob shouldBe "BOB"

    bob.isInitialized shouldBe true
  }

  it should "act since it was initialized" in {
    val lazyBob: Lazy[String] = UnInitializedLazy(() => "Bob")
    val (bob, upperBob) = personToUpper(lazyBob)

    var res: Boolean = false

    upperBob shouldBe "BOB"

    bob.isInitialized shouldBe true
    bob.actIfInitialized(_ => res = true)

    res shouldBe true
  }

  it should "not act since it was not initialized" in {
    val lazyBob: Lazy[String] = UnInitializedLazy(() => "Bob")

    var res: Boolean = false

    lazyBob.isInitialized shouldBe false
    lazyBob.actIfInitialized(_ => res = true)
    lazyBob.isInitialized shouldBe false

    res shouldBe false
  }

  def personToUpper(person: Lazy[String]): (Lazy[String], String) = {
    // Here you will initialize it and do the computing you want.
    // The interest is that you will not need to know how to instanciate Bob
    // since it was defined before, you just do your computations and return a state.
    person.act(p => p.toUpperCase)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but why don't you just shift your logic around like this:

```
object TheApp {
    lazy val optionalSubsystem = {
        // ...
        subsystem
        // more dependencies
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        bootSubsystemA(this)
        bootSubsystemB(this)
    }
}
```

This way "more dependencies" get loaded at the optimal time (including never if they aren't needed)

Comment: In this specific instance, I boot an Akka actor. If the actor is booted, I want to supervise it, but if it wasn't, then I don't want to add it to the supervisor's list, hence the check to see if it was booted.